# jackson @JsonIdentityInfo why?

Tags: java, jackson

entity

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,property="id")
    @Data
    static class Test{
        int id;
        List<Test> list;
    }
```

```
String st = "[{\"id\":1,\"list\":[2,3]},{\"id\":3}]";
        List<Test> test = new ObjectMapper().readerForListOf(Test.class).readValue(st);
        System.out.println(test);
```

out  [Test(id=1, list=[]), Test(id=3, list=null)]

```
String st = "[{\"id\":1,\"list\":[3,2]},{\"id\":3}]";
        List<Test> test = new ObjectMapper().readerForListOf(Test.class).readValue(st);
        System.out.println(test);
```

out [Test(id=1, list=[Test(id=3, list=null)]), Test(id=3, list=null)]

The two pieces of code should output the same result. why different?